# How to plot non-standardized data with ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I plot Iris data with `ggplot2`. It seems `ggplot2` will standardized the data to (0.1) interval automatically. How can I plot the data without any standardized manipulation?

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggpcp(iris, vars = names(iris[1:4]))
p + geom_line(aes(color = Species)) + ylim(0,8)
```

---

I am not a native English speaker and I am sorry to make ambiguity. Actually, the iris data various from 0 to 8. I want to plot the data exactly reflected the real value, but not the standardized value (transform the original data to (0,1) interval).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggpcp(iris, vars = names(iris[1:4]))
iris2 <- data.frame(id=1:nrow(iris), iris)
dat <- reshape2::melt(iris2,id.var = c("id", "Species"))
ggplot(aes(y=value, x=variable, group=id, color=Species), data=dat) + geom_path()
```

[image]

Though there may be better ways.  Never did this so it was fun trying.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a better way. It seems that earlier versions of the `ggpcp()` function had an option for `scale = FALSE` but that was dropped because it depended on the "reshape" package.

Comment: If make make `alpha=0.2` in `geom_path`, the plot isn't so crowded.

Answer (score 6):

The most direct way to do this is probably to use the [GGally package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/index.html). This allows you to do the following:

```
library(GGally)
ggparcoord(iris, columns = 1:4, groupColumn = 5, scale = "globalminmax")
```

which results in:

[image]